# d3 globe cuts off part of the earth when it goes to a particular country

Tags: jquery, svg, d3.js

I have a test site here:
http://newsinteractive.post-gazette.com/test/

When I click the "Countries" tab, then click one of the countries, if the country is in Europe, then part of the globe gets cut off once the globe rotates to that country.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong, please?

Pertinent code:

```
function handleGlobe() {

    //handle globe
    var width = 800,
    height = 800,
    centered;

        var feature;

        var projection = d3.geo.azimuthal()
            .scale(380)
            .origin([-71.03,42.37])
            .mode("orthographic")
            .translate([340, 450]);

        var circle = d3.geo.greatCircle()
            .origin(projection.origin());

        var scale = {
          orthographic: 380,
          stereographic: 380,
          gnomonic: 380,
          equidistant: 380 / Math.PI * 2,
          equalarea: 380 / Math.SQRT2
        };

        var path = d3.geo.path()
            .projection(projection);


        var svg = d3.select("div#globe").append("svg:svg")
            .attr("width", 800)
            .attr("height", 800)
            .on("dblclick", dblclick)
            .on("mousedown", mousedown);

        var g = svg.append("g");

        d3.json("simplified.geojson", function(collection) {

            g.append("g")
              .attr("id", "countries")
            g.append("g")
            .selectAll("path")
              .data(collection.features)
            .enter().append("svg:path")
              .attr("d", clip)
              .attr("id", function(d) { return d.properties.ISO3; })
              .attr("fill", function(d) { return d.properties.FILL; }) //change color and make clickable if data on this country exists
              .on("mouseover", pathOver)
              .on("mouseout", pathOut)
              .on( "dblclick", dblclick)
              .on("mousewheel.zoom", null)
              .on("click", click);

            feature = svg.selectAll("path");

            feature.append("svg:title")
              .text(function(d) { return d.properties.NAME; });


            $('#loader').hide();

        });

        //if a country in the countries tab has been clicked, show info about that country's person
        $('.represented').click(function(){
                var countryabbrev = $(this).attr('id'); 
                if ($(window).width() >= 600){ //rotate globe only if there is a globe to show
                    getCentroid(d3.select("#" + countryabbrev));
                    //projection.origin(projection.invert(#path.centroid(#CAN)));
                    projection.origin(getCentroid(d3.select("#" + countryabbrev)));
                    refresh(1500);
                }
                //showPerson(countryabbrev);
            });

        function getCentroid(selection) {
            // get the DOM element from a D3 selection
            // you could also use "this" inside .each()
            var element = selection.node(),
                // use the native SVG interface to get the bounding box
                bbox = element.getBBox();
                //console.log(projection.invert([bbox.x + bbox.width/2,  bbox.y + bbox.height/2]));
            // return the center of the bounding box
            return projection.invert([bbox.x + bbox.width/2, bbox.y + bbox.height/2]);
        }   

        d3.select(window)
            .on("mousemove", mousemove)
            .on("mouseup", mouseup)
            ;



        var m0,
            o0;

        function mousedown() {
          m0 = [d3.event.pageX, d3.event.pageY];
          o0 = projection.origin();
          d3.event.preventDefault();
        }

        function mousemove() {
          if (m0) {
            var m1 = [d3.event.pageX, d3.event.pageY],
                o1 = [o0[0] + (m0[0] - m1[0]) / 8, o0[1] + (m1[1] - m0[1]) / 8];
            projection.origin(o1);
            circle.origin(o1)
            refresh(1);
          }
        }

        function mouseup() {
          if (m0) {
            mousemove();
            m0 = null;
          }
        }

        function refresh(duration) {
          (duration ? feature.transition().duration(duration) : feature).attr("d", clip);
        }

        function clip(d) {
          return path(circle.clip(d));
        }

        function dblclick(d) {
            zoom = zoom*2;
            projection.origin(projection.invert(d3.mouse(this)));
            projection.scale(zoom);
            refresh(1500);
        }

        function mousewheel(d) {
            zoom = zoom/2;
            projection.origin(projection.invert(d3.mouse(this)));
            projection.scale(zoom);
            refresh(1500);
        }



        function click() {
            thisColor = d3.select(this).style("fill");
            thisCountry = $(this).attr('id');
            //only do popups for countries we have people for
            //|| ()
            if ((thisCountry  == 'GRL') || (thisCountry  == 'ATA') || (thisColor == '#ededed') ) {
                //do nothing
            } else {

                showPerson(thisCountry);
            }//end only for represented countries
        }

        //what to do if a country is selected
        function showPerson(thisCountry) {

            for (var i=0; i<countryAbbrev.length; i++) {
                if (thisCountry == countryAbbrev[i]) {

                    location.hash = countryAbbrev[i];

                    $('#aboutcountry h4').text(countryName[i]);

                    $('#population').text(pop[i] + " million");

                    if (gdp[i].length > 3) {
                        str = gdp[i];
                        /*str1 = str.substring(0, 1);
                        str2 = str.substring(2, str.length);
                        str = str1 + "." + str2;*/
                        num = parseInt(str);
                        num = (num/1000).toFixed(3);
                        $('#gdp').text("$" + num + " trillion");
                    } else {
                        $('#gdp').text("$" + gdp[i] + " billion");
                    }

                    $('#income').text(income[i]);

                    break;
                }
            }

            $('#grayout').fadeIn( function () {
                var screenTop = $(document).scrollTop();
                var personTop = screenTop + 10;
                $('#person_wrapper').css('top', personTop + 'px');


                $('#person_wrapper').fadeIn();
                //center person-wrapper
                w = $('#person_wrapper').width();
                winW = $(window).width();
                mL = (winW - w)/2;
                if ($(window).width() > 600) {
                    $('#person_wrapper').css('margin-left', mL + "px");
                    var wrapHeight = $('#person_wrapper').height();
                    var notesHeight = wrapHeight - $('#nameSpace').height() - $('#vidspace').height() - $('#personInfo').height() - 90; //90 = vertical whitespaces
                    $('#Notes').css('height', notesHeight + 'px');
                    var imageColHeight = .95 * wrapHeight;
                    $('#personImages').css('height', imageColHeight + 'px');
                }




            });
        }

        function pathOver() {
            thisID = $(this).attr('id');
            thisColor = d3.select(this).style("fill");
            if (thisColor == '#ededed') {
                $(this).css('cursor', 'auto');
                $(this).css('opacity', '1');
            }   
            if (thisColor == '#aaaaaa')
            {
                $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
                $(this).css('opacity', '.7');
            }   
            if ((thisID  == 'GRL') || (thisID  == 'ATA')){
                $(this).css('cursor', 'auto');
                $(this).css('opacity', '1');
            } 
        }

        function pathOut() {
            $(this).css('opacity', '1');
        }

        $('.searchsurround1').click(function(){
            zoom = zoom*2;
            projection.scale(zoom);
            refresh(1500);
        });

        $('.searchsurround2').click(function(){
            zoom = zoom/2;
            projection.scale(zoom);
            refresh(1500);
        });
        //end globe


    //adjust globe's position so it's centered
    mL = $('svg').css('margin-left');
    mL = mL.substring(0, mL.length-2);
    mL -= 400;
    $('svg').css('margin-left', mL + "px");



    }//end handling globe variables
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click a country, the `click` function calls the `showPerson` function, which shows the information modal. In this function, the window gets scrolled, hidding the top of the chart.

```
    //what to do if a country is selected
    function showPerson(thisCountry) {

        for (var i=0; i<countryAbbrev.length; i++) {
           // ... mode code here ...
        }

        $('#grayout').fadeIn( function () {

            // -- HERE -- 
            var screenTop = $(document).scrollTop();
            var personTop = screenTop + 10;
            $('#person_wrapper').css('top', personTop + 'px');

       })
       // more code ...
```

The project looks great, you may want to use [TopoJSON](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson) instead of GeoJSON. TopoJSON files are about 80% smaller than equivalent GeoJSON files with the same information. Regards,

Pablo.

Comment: When I comment out the showPerson command, the globe still gets cut off...but something to think about. Do you know please where to find a good topojson file of all countries?

Comment: You can generate one using `topojson -o countries.topojson countries.geojson`. Check the [command line options](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/Command-Line-Reference) if you need to preserve properties of the attributes.

Comment: I've been playing with topojson, but found out this piece of information: "The canvas element is part of HTML5, and allows to draw elements on a raster. It's different from SVG, since once a shape is drawn, there is *no way to modify it or style it*. And *no event handlers* on every shape can be set. The memory use of a Canvas is then much lower than the one used by the same drawing using SVG, since there is no DOM to handle.
 (emphasis mine)

Comment: If I can't style each country (shape) on the fly and attach event handlers to shapes, then topojson won't work for me.

Comment: TopoJSON is just the file format, you can transform the TopoJSON object to GeoJSON using the `topojson.feature` method. If you need to attach events to the shapes, I would recommend using SVG. Neither GeoJSON nor TopoJSON are related to canvas or SVG. [Here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4206573) is an example of TopoJSON with SVG.